# how to use jquery in javascript file included in angular.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular8

i am using a javascript file that use jquery in it ..
to use this js file i put it in script array in angular.json file
and put also the jquery in the same array before this file.
but when i run the angular project it get me

```
missing declare for $
```

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
   "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
   "node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js",
   "assets/js/theme.js"
]
```

the file theme.js is the one that use jquery in it.

Comment: Why use jQuery and Angular together? Just don't do that, for me it's a big nono. Jquery manipulates the DOM, and Angular generates the DOM on the fly. They have no idea of each other's presence and actions, and this will necessary lead to an unmaintainable application full of workarounds. Not to mention that you have to load two libraries instead of one. Use one or the other, not both together.

Answer (score 1):

To Install `JQuery` follow below steps

1. install jQuery using npm as

   `npm install jquery — save`
2. Navigate to the ./angular-cli.json file at the root of your Angular CLI project folder, and find the scripts: [] property, and include the path to jQuery

   `"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]`
3. Now you have to do is to import it in whatever component you want to use jQuery

   ```
   import * as $ from 'jquery';
   (or)
   declare var $: any;
   ```

Comment: Note that it is recommended to use JQuery installed by npm and include it in the angular-cli.json file as shown by @manikant if you intent to use it in you typescript files

Comment: For me it's a heresy to use jQuery and Angular in the same app. They are completely antagonist and can't lead to a clean application.

Comment: the problem is not to use it in the component, it dosen't work in the js file like bootstrap that use jquery

Comment: @HassanAhmed use jquery prior to bootstrap js

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed JQuery using **npm install jquery**
You need to additionally install types as well.

Install types for jquery using

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

and for using jquery in your component you need to use :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: For me it's a heresy to use jQuery and Angular in the same app. They are completely antagonist and can't lead to a clean application.

Comment: the problem is not to use it in the component, it dosen't work in the js file like bootstrap that use jquery